# How to handle a dependent variable with sub-dimensions and multiple independent variables with sub-dimensions?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, dimensions

The variables X1, X2 and Y consist of several dimensions (based on the corresponding literature), which we asked about in advance using Likert items (1-5).

However, I am not quite sure how to analyze the variables correctly, as I have not found any literature where both dependent and independent variables are tested on multiple dimensions.

My approach would be as follows:

1. test a classical regression model of the aggregated variables X1 and X2 and their interaction on Y to basically see if and how X1 and X2 affect Y.
2. analyze Y in a multivariate regression, but consider X1 and X2 in the aggregated form.
3. consider Y as an aggregated variable and test X1 and X2 through a commonality analysis to reveal the dependencies between them.
4. combine some kind of multivariate regression (to shed light on the sub-dimensions of Y) with a commonality analysis (to shed light on the sub-dimensions of X1 and X2).

My approach seems very vague to me and I am not sure if this is scientifically correct at all. Does anyone have any tips or experiences or papers that can help me to deal correctly with (un)dependent variables including sub-dimensions?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into structural equation modelling?  I am not a big fan of this method, but it seems suited to your case.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I've just a had a look into SEM and (at a first glance) this seems to be what I was looking for.